# Bash script: Download html file, compare with previous version and display the difference

Tags: html, regex, bash, xslt, diff

This website lists a few IP addresses which might change over the time.
https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH244698.html

Now I would like to write a bash script (must be bash, python or PHP can't be used) which would download the above mentioned html file once and then compare the new version towards the old one each time the script is run. If there is a difference, it should be displayed, logged to a file and, in a later step, an email notification should be sent.

Now, this seems to be an easy task in theory, but I am unable to produce any results. I would appreciate if I can get some ideas on how to achieve this.

So far I have tried the following approaches:

```
#!/bin/bash
#check website for changes

URL="https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH244698.html"



mv  new.html old.html 2> /dev/null
curl -v --silent $URL --stderr - > new.html
diff -y --suppress-common-lines new.html old.html
```

And

```
URL="https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH244698.html"


for (( ; ; )); do
mv new.html old.html 2> /dev/null
curl $URL -L --compressed -s > new.html
DIFF_OUTPUT="$(diff new.html old.html)"
if [ "0" != "${#DIFF_OUTPUT}" ]; then
... ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way to extract the IP addresses (that's the only part of the html that is of interest to me)

Comment: which ip do you want exactly? The ones under IP subnet in the table or all of them?

Comment: The goal would be to monitor all of the IP addresses listed on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#check website for changes

URL="https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH244698.html"


if [ -f new_ips.log ]; then
    mv  new_ips.log old_ips.log 2> /dev/null
fi

curl --silent "$URL" | \
grep -oP '\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(:?\/\d\d?)?\b' > new_ips.log

if [ -f new_ips.log ] && [ -f old_ips.log ]; then
        diff -y --suppress-common-lines new_ips.log old_ips.log
        exit 0;
fi

exit 1;
```

The first time you need to run it twice, since initially there is nothing to compare to.

**Explanations:**

You were really close to a working solution, by adding the `grep -oP '\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(:?\/\d\d?)?\b'` that will fetch only the ips of the html file you can focus on what you are really interested into and avoid having differences in the page design or timestamp etc.

I have tested it by modifying the new_ips.log before rerunning it and you have the following differences:

```
./check_ips.sh 
                                                              > 142.64.0.0/21
148.64.0.0/21                                                 | 142.64.0.1
148.64.0.1                                                    <
```

Comment: Allan, thank you for your input. That gives me exactly the output that I need for all further steps, e.g. notification on the screen and email etc.

Comment: May I ask another question? I would like to archive the logs from the past in a seperate folder, preferably with a timestamp either inside the logfile or in the filename. This could be achieved with the date command I suppose. So now I create a cronjob to run this script once a day, say each morning at 8am and I would like to have one week of logs (rotating) - e.g. the folder should contain Mon_&date_log, Tue_%date_log and so on at the end of the week - the following week it should overwrite the files. Can this behavior be achieved with a bash script?

Comment: @i716: yes you should use the `find` command with options to find all the files that are older than a specific time stamp and move/compress them. using `exec` option or `xargs` :-)

Comment: I have added, the following lines as below `DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")

if [ -f new_ips.log ]; then
    cp  new_ips.log logfiles/$DATE.log
    mv  new_ips.log old_ips.log 2> /dev/null
fi ` for the first task. It creates the log files each time the script is run. The weeksday is not actually necessary.

Comment: I will find a way to achieve this. But getting back to Regex, is there a viable way to include the country name with the IP addresses? e.g., Auckland, NZ IP address, Sydney, AU IP address?

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your second question in which you want to add the list of countries to your IP addresses. Like `Auckland, NZ IP address, Sydney, AU IP address`.

I propose to change the extraction/filtering command in the following way:

1) we will need to parse the `HTML` document using a parser (xslt technologies are enough for what we want to achieve)

```
more generate_ips.xslt 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
        <xsl:output method="text"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:for-each select="/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/strong|/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet will print the country name and the ips with a line feed character after them by accessing them via their `xpath`.

2) The `curl` command is changed in the following way:

```
curl --silent "$URL" |\
 awk 'BEGIN{print "<html><body>"}/<table/{a=1;}/<\/table>/{print;a=0}{if(a)print;}END{print "</body></html>"}' |\
 xsltproc -html generate_ips.xslt - | sed '/^Egress/{d};s/^ *//'
```

You use `awk` to extract all the tables and create a simplified html file with only the ip tables we are interested into. Then you call the XSLT processor to produce the output and last but not least sed will remove lines that are not required and clean the display

**OUTPUT:**

```
IP address range**
148.64.0.0/21**
148.64.0.0/21
148.64.0.1
148.64.7.254
Auckland, New Zealand
124.157.113.128/27 124.157.113.160/27 124.157.113.192/27
124.157.113.129 124.157.113.161 124.157.113.193
124.157.113.158 124.157.113.190 124.154.113.222
Chennai, India
180.179.40.0/26 180.179.46.64/27 148.64.6.0/23
180.179.40.1 180.179.46.65 148.64.6.1
180.179.40.62 180.179.46.94 148.64.7.254
Hong Kong
103.246.38.0/24 148.64.0.0/24
103.246.38.1 148.64.0.1
103.246.38.254 148.64.0.254
Mumbai, India
180.179.142.0/24 148.64.4.0/23
180.179.142.1 148.64.4.1
180.179.142.254 148.64.5.254
Seoul, South Korea
203.246.168.0/24
203.246.168.1
203.246.168.254
Shanghai, China
211.147.76.0/27 211.147.76.32/27
211.147.76.1 211.147.76.33
211.147.76.30 211.147.76.62
Singapore
103.246.37.0/24 148.64.3.0/24
103.246.37.1 148.64.3.1
103.246.37.254 148.64.3.254
Sydney, Australia
103.246.36.0/24
103.246.36.1
103.246.36.254
Taipei, Taiwan
61.58.46.0/24
61.58.46.1
61.58.46.254
Tokyo, Japan
103.9.99.0/24 103.246.39.0/24 148.64.1.0/24 
103.9.99.1 103.246.39.1 148.64.1.1
103.9.99.254 103.246.39.254 148.64.1.254
```

The rest of the script should not be changed and works well as it is.

Comment: Allan, you are great! Thank you. But may I ask where the part in 1) should be implemented? Maybe I should mention that no external software can be installed on the system, hence my request to do it all in a bash script.

Comment: regarding the part1 just create a file called `generate_ips.xslt` and write the content in it. You should have a XSLT processor command on your system. Do you have `xsltproc`? `xalan`, `saxon`? If you have `xsltproc` you don't have to change anything if you do not have check for the xsltproc that is installed on your machine and change xsltproc with your command!

Comment: It seems like im lucky with that `[root@iprx2061 ito-20180612]# which xsltproc
/usr/bin/xsltproc` I will try your suggestion!

Comment: I have just tried it, unfortunately, it produces the following error: `generate_ips.xslt:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
more generate_ips.xslt
^
cannot parse generate_ips.xslt
generate_ips.xslt:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
more generate_ips.xsltgenera`

Comment: `$more generate_ips.xslt` is just the command `more` and your `FILENAME` (to read the content of the file lol) the first line of the file `generate_ips.xslt` should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and not `more generate_ips.xslt`

Comment: @i716: just check this quick fix and let me know

Comment: That was indeed very stupid of me not to realize that lol Sorry. Well, it works as in that it displays the output on the screen but it doesn't write it into a file. I have simplified the script for testing purposes. It now just curls the URL, followed by your latest code, then comes the regex from yesterday followed by a `> filename`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173372/discussion-between-allan-and-i716).